# Alternative to PTRACE_PEEKDATA for large reads

Tags: linux, debugging

I'm trying to read a large struct(3MB) from an inferior process to debug it and I was wondering if there is a more efficient alternative than iterating over ptrace()?

I've tried process_vm_readv() but it's not available in the bionic libc.

Is ptrace() thread safe? Since that may be an option.

Comment: If `/proc` is available then `pread64` or (`lseek()` and `read()` can be used on file `/proc/PID/mem` in order to read data. This is a way `gdb` gets info from a debugged process. However gdb **stops** process before getting info from it. This is why it is thread safe under gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `/proc` is available then `pread64` or (`lseek()` and `read()`) can be used on file `/proc/PID/mem` in order to read data. This is a way `gdb` gets info from a debugged process. However `gdb` stops process before getting info from it. This is why it is thread safe under `gdb`